# Plotting an ECG graphic using jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart, graphic

Here's the deal, Im creating a java program that reads data from a microcontroller, the microcontroller sends the heart rate for the application (so I have a list containing the data), everything is working fine, but now, I wanna know how can I plot the data in a jfreechart graphic ?

So what do you guys recommend for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JFreeChart to display recent changes in a time series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048852/using-jfreechart-to-display-recent-changes-in-a-time-series)